# Libevent does not echo properly when there is a delay

Tags: caching, network-programming, libevent

Based on the following code, I built a version of an echo server, but with a threaded delay. This was built because I've noticed that upon initial connection, my first send is sent back to the client, but the client does not receive it until a second send. My real-world use case is that I need to send messages to the server, do a lot of processing, and then send the result back... say 10-30 seconds later (could be hours in some cases).

http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref8_listener.html

So here is my code. For brevity's sake, I have only included the libevent-related code; not the threading code or other stuff. When debugging, a new connection is set up, the string buffer is filled properly, and debugging reveals that the writes go successfully.

http://pastebin.com/g02S2RTi

But I only receive the echo from the send-before-last. I send from the client numbers to validate this and when I send a 1 from the client, I receive nothing from the server via echo... even though the server is definitely writing to the buffer using evbuffer_add ( I have also tried this using bufferevent_write_buffer).

From the client when I send a 2, I then receive the 1 from the previous send. It's like my writes are being cached.... I have turned off nagle.

So, my question is: Does libevent cache sends using the following method?

evbuffer_add( outputBuffer, buffer, length );

Is there a way to flush this cache? Is there some other method to mark the cache as finished or complete? Can I force a send? It never sends on it's own... I have even put in delays. Replacing evbuffer_add with "send" works perfectly every time.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are affected by [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) - basically it buffers outgoing data, before sending it to the network. Take a look at this article: [TCP/IP options for high-performance data transmission](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tcp-ip-options-for-high-performance-data-transmission/).

Here is an example how to disable buffering:

```
 int flag = 1;
 int result = setsockopt(sock,            /* socket affected */
                         IPPROTO_TCP,     /* set option at TCP level */
                         TCP_NODELAY,     /* name of option */
                         (char *) &flag,  /* the cast is historical
                                                 cruft */
                         sizeof(int));    /* length of option value */
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It turns out that threading was the big issue. By adding the following to the top of my main, before the creation of libevent, everything worked fine.

 evthread_use_windows_threads(); (pthread for linux)